# scalac compiler error from IntelliJ (Play Framework) Assertion failed

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6 CE

I'm used to compiling my app from sbt in the terminate (which works).  I'd like to use the debugging features of IDEA and not have to overlook false-negative errors.

The Project is set to compile scala 2.10.4 with JDK 1.8.0_25 ant project language level 8.0 (this also happens with language level 7.0).

Here is the stacktrace when I "Make Module" in IDEA. It's failing on a particular Twirl *.template.scala file, but it fails on other files as well, such as the generated `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/controllers/routes.java` file

```
== Expanded type of tree ==
ConstantType(value = Constant(play.twirl.api.Html))
uncaught exception during compilation: java.lang.AssertionError
Error:scalac: Error: assertion failed: List(object package$Stopwatch, object package$Stopwatch)
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(object package$Stopwatch, object package$Stopwatch)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.suchThat(Symbols.scala:1678)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$ClassSymbol.companionModule0(Symbols.scala:2988)
  at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$ClassSymbol.companionModule(Symbols.scala:2991)
  at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$JPlainBuilder.genClass(GenASM.scala:1371)
  at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.GenASM$AsmPhase.run(GenASM.scala:120)
  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1583)
  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1557)
  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1553)
  at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1662)
  at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:126)
  at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)
  at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
  at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
  at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:28)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:64)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:22)
  at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
```

This gist has the full AST for the Template: https://gist.github.com/joshm1/1615d75925dcdb3bc23e

Comment: Note: even after I compile the project in SBT, it does a full recompile when I try to immediately compile it in IDEA.  Shouldn't it detect that nothing changed and finish right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by running `sbt test:compile` from command line and then running Make Module in IntelliJ.  Just running `sbt compile` did not help.

The following pages are related to my issue:

Twirl apparently doesn't compile in IDEA CE - https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5528393#5528393

Compiler crash for a package object containing a class and companion
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5954